# How to stop an infinite loop in autohotkey using the key you start it with

Tags: loops, toggle, autohotkey

So i just started using autohotkey and i made this script to spam the trade chat in a game called path of exile, it works pretty well, but i cant get it to stop when i press f1 again, i've tried countles times, but the loop just won't stop

```
#MaxThreads 2
wintitle=Path of Exile
SetTitleMatchMode,2
DetectHiddenWindows,On
setkeydelay,2500,0
f1::
toggle:=!toggle
Loop
{
  if toggle
    controlsend,,{enter}{up}{enter}, %wintitle%
  else
    break
}
return
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you're better off using [SetTimer](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm) for this. Loops aren't very easy to work with when it comes to toggles.

```
i := 0
toggle := 0
F1::
    toggle := !toggle
    if (toggle) {
        SetTimer, Timer_Spam, 10
    } else {
        SetTImer, Timer_Spam, Off
    }
return

Timer_Spam:
    TrayTip, Counter, %i%
    i++
return
```

The reason why your loop isn't working is because once you enter the loop the program is stuck there, so to get out you need to work from inside the loop.

You can do this with [GetKeyState()](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm), but then you can't use the same key to toggle it on and off, as it'll toggle off as soon as you start it, unless you add `Sleep` commands in there, in which case it becomes unreliable instead.

You can however use a separate key to stop the loop, shown here.

```
toggle := 0
i := 0
F1::
    toggle := !toggle
    if (toggle) {
        Loop {
            if (GetKeyState("F2", "P")) {
                toggle := !toggle
                break
            }

            TrayTip, Counter, %i%
            i++
        }   
    }
return
```

But like I said above, `SetTimer` achieves the same result in a much more stable way. So I'd go with that.

Comment: Thanks for the help man, i really appreciate it, your second code worked, all i have to do is hold f2

Answer (score 3):

use `MaxThreadsPerHotkey`

```
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2
wintitle=Path of Exile
SetTitleMatchMode,2
DetectHiddenWindows,On
setkeydelay,2500,0
return

f1::
toggle:=!toggle
Loop
{
if toggle
controlsend,,{enter}{up}{enter}, %wintitle%
else
break
}
return
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i tried it, but it still didn't work - the loop kept going after pressing f1 again

Answer (score 3):

Working example with Loop command. Yet so simple.

```
#Persistent
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2
toggle := False

f1 UP::
toggle := !toggle

Loop {
    If (!toggle) {
        break
    }
    ; Spam commands here
}
Return
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the easiest approach I was able to do.

Start/stop toggle with key "2", sending "a" with 0.1 second delay.

```
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2

running := false
stop := false

~2::

if(!running) {
    running := true
}
else {
    stop := true
    return
}

loop {

    Send {a} ; example sending key "a"

    if(stop) {
        running := false
        stop := false
        break
    }

    Sleep, 100

}

return
```

Answer (score 2):

My strategy is this,
Use this command:

```
 v::
loop
{
click
if (GetKeyState("b")) {
break
    }
}
return
```

(Its simple AutoClicker)

Answer (score 1):

This code does what you want:

```
#MaxThreads 2
wintitle=Path of Exile
SetTitleMatchMode,2
DetectHiddenWindows,On
setkeydelay,2500,0

return
F1::
    Loop
    {

        CheckLButton1:
       if (GetKeyState("F1"))
        {
            Goto, CheckLButton1
        }

        Docode:
        controlsend,,{enter}{up}{enter}, %wintitle%
        ;ToolTip, 1


        if (!(GetKeyState("F1")))
        {
            Goto, Docode
        }

        CheckLButton2:
       if (!(GetKeyState("F1")))
        {
            return
        }
        else
        {
            Goto, CheckLButton2
        }
    }
return
```

If you need explanation, look here at my post: http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=4613#p26298